# syntax matching of a string in java

Tags: java, string, syntax, string-matching

In Java, I want to write a syntax matcher.

For `string1: a = a+b, and string2: c = c+d, syntax_matcher(string1,string2) = true.`

However, `if string1 : a > 0; string2 : c == 0, syntax_matcher(string1,string2) = false.`

Any idea, how to do that efficiently?

Comment: create a custom class with your matcher methods, override equals method for your requirement.

Comment: @PremGenError Regex won't work its CFG problem.

Comment: Are you matching on the statements' "program structure"? If yes, then you might need to parse the text into an abstract syntax tree and compare these. Could be overkill, though.

Comment: @PremGenError Context-free grammar. may be :/

Comment: @PremGenError Context Free Grammar :)

Comment: @ShivamKalra hard to tell with the data the user gives, it depends of how simple its syntax is

Answer (score 4):

Maybe what you could do would be to write a `Stack` and for the first statement move from left to right, pushing values like `VAR` then `ASSIGNMENT`, then `VAR`, then `OPERATOR` then `VAR`.

Once you have that, you could start for the second expression and move from **right to left**, each time comparing what you have with what you have popped from the stack.

Any mismatch between what you are reading and what you have popped would yield `false`.

Comment: Might fail for `a = a + b * c` and `d = b * c + d`. Both same syntaxes.

Comment: @ShivamKalra: If it is left to be generic enough (just `VAR` and `OPERATOR`), it should not fail for that case.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [LR-parser (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser) to parse the expressions, since they probably are a **context-free language**. For Java, you may want to use e.g. the [CUP open-source parser generator](http://www2.cs.tum.edu/projects/cup/).

Then compare the resulting [syntax trees (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) using your favorite tree comparison method.

See [Chomsky Hierarchy (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy) for the differentiation of regular and context-free languages.